# "Windows Update" text using strange characters

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview

I'm seeing strange characters used to render the words "Windows Update". View the screenshots below to see what I mean.

Is this a known 'easter egg' from devs or is something else going on?

Model: Lumia 640 XL LTE

OS build: 10.0.15223.0

Language: English (United Kingdom)

[image: Settings menu]

Comment: This is not the first instance of such characters. On certain versions of Windows 10 other features in the Settings app had such names. There is probably some Joker in the team developing the Mobile variant :)

Comment: The text is normal again in build 15228

Comment: [Pseudo English looking characters used in Windows 10 Insider Preview](https://superuser.com/q/1340277/241386)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These looks like "pseudo localised" text - i.e. it's practically in English, but uses non-latin characters to check that character encoding issues haven't been introduced, and that everything that should be localised is (i.e. it's obviously wrong, but the QA staff can identify the meaning, rather than just seeing a blank label).

This is a common practice used by different software houses, and it looks like in this case the translation was missed in that specific insider build.

Comment: Funny how it isn't a first. But good point!